# Extending the "Your first question has been published, now what?" system

Tags: feature-request, new-users

Currently when new users publish their first question, a little box pops up that says

> Your first question has been published, now what?

I'm proposing to extend this system. When the user posts their first answer (I don't recall whether a box pops up there), when they receives the first answer for their question, when their question/edit/answer was first deleted/accepted... Many "firsts" could use a gentle pop-up that serves as complement to the Tour and Help Page system.

This system does not even need to be limited to newbies -- When users are first granted review privilege, or vote down, or close vote...  a box should pop up to hint them on how to use such moderation privileges to improve the site.

A suggestion for the "first received answer" scenario.

> ### Your question received an answer!
>
> #### Now what?
>
> - You may comment on it to communicate with the author and make the answer clearer.
> - You may upvote it if you think the answer is beneficial to the community.
> - You may accept it if you think the answer solves your problem.

Comment: It would address the issue of people feeling like they need to leave comments explaining how to accept an answer, so I'm for it.

Comment: There's already a message sent when a user unlocks review queues. I know because I still have the emails from the times when I unlocked review queues for the 18th, 19th, and 20th time. (Can't disable without stopping swag emails.) There's also that popup that I'm still seeing in my face, whenever I visit a queue on a site for the first time. Bottom line: I really don't want to hear about it unless it's a network first!

Answer (score 8):

I have some other suggestions for the text you suggested:

> ### Your question received an answer!
>
> #### Now what?
>
> - Go see if it solved your problem, test it out.
> - You may comment on it to ask the author for clarification.
> - You may show your gratitude by either:
>
>   - Upvoting the answer if you found it helpful.
>   - Accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

I shortened the sentences; the shorter they are, the better they are understood.
And I inserted a bit about showing gratitude, which could also be worded as "thanks".

I removed the bits about "if you think" because ideally you test an answer before you accept it, so I put that as a first step.

Comment: Maybe make this into a community wiki so we can think of texts for more scenarios here?

Comment: You can't test it out in certain SEs, e.g. WorldBuilding, or those scenarios that you really only get one attempt at